# Multiple Urns With a Pre-Defined Probability Mass Function

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Say we have 20 identical urns containing red and green balls; in our experiment, we will select 8 balls from each urn.

Suppose that for each individual urn, the probability of drawing *k* green balls out of 8 is given as follows:

| *k* | probability |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 60.0% |
| 1 | 24.5% |
| 2 | 4.0% |
| 3 | 3.4% |
| 4 | 2.8% |
| 5 | 2.2% |
| 6 | 1.6% |
| 7 | 1.0% |
| 8 | 0.5% |

In our experiment, what is the probability that we will draw a combined total of exactly 10 green balls from the 20 urns?

What method (or methods) can we use to solve this problem for the general case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{P}(X_i=k) = a_k$ where $X_i$ is the number of green balls from the $i$-th urn. The $X_i$ are two by two independent, and we search for the law of $\sum_{i=1}^{20}X_i$.
It is easy to see that $\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2 = n) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_ka_n-k$.
If we define the discrete convolution $f*g = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}f(k)g(n-k)$, then we have $\mathbb{P}_{X_1+X_2} = \mathbb{P}_{X_1}*\mathbb{P}_{X_2}$.
More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent variables, we have $\mathbb{P}_{X+Y} = \mathbb{P}_{X}*\mathbb{P}_{Y}$. So we need to compute $\mathbb{P}_{X_1}*\mathbb{P}_{X_2}*...*\mathbb{P}_{X_{20}}$. The discrete convolution is associative (and commutative), so you can use exponentiation by squaring. For the convolution itself, if the number of balls grows, you can also rely on Fast Fourier Transform. For calculating the power, there are also [tricks relying on the Fourier Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102496/a-naive-and-easy-formula-to-calculate-convolution-power).

We can link it to polynomials this way :
Let $P(x) = \sum_{i=1}^8 a_ix^i$. Then the desired value is the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $P^{20}(x)$

Comment: Thank you for the rapid answer! The 20-term convolution seems a bit daunting to an amateur like me... is there any way to construct it using something like the Bell Polynomials?

Comment: I don't think there is something more simple and canonical than expressing it as the $20$-th power of a convolution. A convolution is not that complex, (unless we start toying with Fourier Transform, but that is not mandatory), and can be implemented easily. (lots of packages have built-in for convolution also). To compute the $20$-fold convolution, I don't see many libraries that have it (but maybe I searched too quickly). Implementing exponentiation by squaring is not very difficult.

Comment: Thank you once again; I was able to get my answer in the end using a very ...interesting method for computing the 20-fold convolution: for exactly 10 total green out of 20 urns at 8 draws each, I computed a probability of approximately 4.23%.